# Using PropTypes.string in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-proptypes

I am trying to use `react-native-gifted-chat` in my app but when I build the app is getting me the following error.

[image]

While I am looking on line 46 from Chat.js it looks like this.

```
45 Chat.propTypes = {
46   name: React.PropTypes.string,
47 };
```

Any idea what is wrong in this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the latest documentation of `React`, you need to use [`PropTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) in the following way as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), since this package has been separated from `React` module

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

Chat.propTypes = {
   name: PropTypes.string,
 };
```